# How to perform an "UPDATE" with elixir

Tags: python, sql, flask, python-elixir

I'm using elixir/flask in a small web app I wrote for my own personal aggregator.

I'm trying to create a restful call to mark all items of a particular rssfeed as read.

The SQL statement would look something like `UPDATE model_rssitems set hasbeenseen = 1 where rssfeed_id = '%s' % feedid`

I don't know how to write the code to make elixir perform that action and when I tried to use session.execute I get an error saying `UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session`

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you haven't used the `bind` expression yet :)

Your code requires something like this to tell `Elixir` what database you're using.

```
from elixir import metadata
metadata.bind = 'sqlite:///your_database_file.sqlite'
metadata.bind.echo = True
```

Comment: Well the metadata.bind exists in my model.py but not in the controller part of my code. I tried adding that line to the function for the page to update the rssitems but it produced the same error

Comment: @Gekitsuu: in that case you might have forgotten the `elixir.setup_all()` call at the bottom of the models file.

Comment: I have setup_all() and create_all() at the bottom of my model.py

Comment: @Gekitsuu: in that case I can't really think of a reason why it shouldn't work. Just maybe it's not working because of some other elixir imports or something, but that's just a wild guess.